# I typed booking.com and my Google Chrome forwarded me via rstyle.com to an affiliate link - How to debug this?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I typed `www.booking.com` into Chrome and I saw `rstyle.me` and then I was sent to:

```
https://www.booking.com/?aid=803127&label=affnetcj-12010984_pub-2975314_site-4441350_clkid-.MzYwMTMyLTA.029b2c08-d3ee-11ea-89ae-b3cda94859e2_cjevent-038ade63d3ee11ea81b9004d0a18050e_pname-rewardStyle&utm_source=affnetcj&utm_medium=bannerindex&utm_campaign=us&utm_term=index-12010984
```

Which is an affiliate link. I've had this issue before with [this plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ratings-preview-for-youtu/cgbhdenfmgbagncdmgbholejjpmmiank?hl=en) that hijacked 10% of all my search queries to Yahoo Search.

Comment: Most probably the browser just helpfully completed `booking.com` to a previous URL.

Comment: https://malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner